# Non-logged in users - attempting to vote doesn't explain why you can't

Tags: bug, status-norepro, voting

Just visited SO and for some reason I wasn't logged in (strange, I was last night), but didn't notice and then tried to upvote an answer.  I got the orange box popup which I thought used to say "you need XXX reputation to vote" or similar but instead I got this:

[image]

which I presume should have said something else in there as well as "click to dismiss" :-)

If it helps, FF 3.6 on Ubuntu 10.10...

Comment: The messagebox was speechless ;-). Nice catch.

Comment: Can you re-reproduce?

Comment: Not so far although I'm temporarily away from the machine I had it on.  Can't reproduce on FF on a mac.  Thinking it may have been in the (brief) period between not being logged in and the auto-login taking place though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce this -- I visited SO in chrome incognito mode, clicked upvote, and got the standard box:

> #### Please login or register to vote for this post.
>
> (click on this box to dismiss)

Comment: Have to say I can't reproduce it now either, although the screenshot above was after I'd clicked upvote a couple of times too. Very bizarre, although as I put above, I have a feeling it may be linked to the interstitial period when the automatic login is happening.