# Non-logged in votes by known users

Tags: feature-request, voting, anonymous-visitors

For those of us who are members of a number of other sites, but don't want to sign up to certain sites (for whatever reason), simplify the "Vote noted; you have not got an account here." dialogue box back to the simple orange popup with text similar to what I've just quoted.

So, I'm asking, for accounts you know about because they say "Join this community", instead of this big dialogue box when you click on a voting button:

[image: great hulking dialogue box]

revert to (a working version of) the orange message shown on [this (old) question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73183/non-logged-in-users-attempting-to-vote-doesnt-explain-why-you-cant?rq=1), which under the current UI is probably a red message similar to:

[image: Simple red message]

(I know the non-logged in votes on posts has been demoted but not removed. I would also suggest promoting those again.)

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you're talking about? We do not record *votes* for users who don't have a profile on the site. We gather anonymous feedback, but that's different. I'm not sure what you mean by "non-logged in votes on post have been demoted". There's been no changes in that area in years at this point.

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to "anonymous feedback" you receive when we click on the voting buttons when we're on a site where we don't have an account, but, as of the new changes, you do know we exist.

Comment: And, yes, I understand the "demotion" of "anonymous feedback" has been so for a fair while now. Some of us have been around long enough to still recall it :-)

Comment: So what are you asking for? For votes to be network-account-based, or...? I'm not sure what you mean by the orange popup.

Comment: @AnnaLear No, I'm not asking for network-account-based votes (not that I wouldn't necessarily like that idea somewhat); just a simplification of the dialogue box when we're known to not have an account, similar to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260723/dont-show-the-how-does-se-work-banner-to-users-who-have-accounts-on-other-sit) which prompted mine.

Answer (score 6):

We have no plans to remove that popup right now - anonymous feedback still gotta be tracked, if nothing else, and we still want to show off the newsletter to folks who perhaps don't want to join the site and create a profile.

Having said all that, I'm working on a lot of UI improvements as part of the universal login project, and changing that popup to mimic the top bar and say "join this community" is on the list.

We have idly considered changing up that dialog more, but that'll be a separate project if/when it happens.

<sub>(As a side note, when you do log in through that dialog, your anon "vote" is supposed to be converted to a real vote. That appears to be broken right now, though I'm not 100% sure why yet. Gonna need to dig deeper.)</sub>